# Conditional iloc statement. "Time series analysis"

Tags: python

In Python, I have a  data set with several rows and columns. If the value of one `column=X` I am interested in the value of the row above it and the column to the right so plus `[1,1]` from the previous location of value x.

What's the best way to approach this? If `cell =X`, is there a dynamic way I can get the location and then add X amount of rows and columns to it "since I am interested in the value of that cell"?

[Visual Example of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwla9.png)

Comment: can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Hi Marat, I shared an image link to hopefully make this a bit clearer. It is very easy for me to do this in Excel, I am just trying to learn how to do this in Python. The Excel logic would be =If(A5=4,b4,"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say our array is defined as:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[9, 8, 4, 5, 2],
                [0, 3, 5, 6, 7],
                [6, 6, 2, 0, 6],
                [2, 0, 2, 5, 8],
                [2, 6, 9, 7, 9]])
```

A straight forward solution is to just loop through the column of interest.

```
colIndex = 2
X = 2
rDelta = -1 #row change, up is negative!
cDelta = 1 #col change, right is positive

numberRows = np.shape(arr)[1]
output = []

#This loops through all the values in the specified column and looks for 
#matches, if a match is found it is added to an output list
#Note that we only look at values that would result in valid output
#   for example we will not look at the first row if 
#   we would need to index into the row above for the output
for i in range(max(-rDelta,0),min(numberRows,numberRows-rDelta)):
    if(arr[i,colIndex]==X):
        #replace this with your processing
        output.append(arr[i+rDelta,colIndex+cDelta])
```

After running this code I get that output as

```
[6, 0]
```

which are the values up and to the right of the 2's in the second column.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. I still have to work through the function a bit to understand. I have a lot of studying to do.